# Error while trying to run npm run build

Tags: spring, angular, spring-boot, package

I have created a simple app with `Spring Boot` and `Angular 4`. I tried to run a script which will pack every (`npm run build`) file from frontend file to the `src/main/resources/static` file. But I am getting an error which is:

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.15063
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build"
npm ERR! node v6.9.4
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! tasks@0.0.0 postbuild: `npm run deploy`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the tasks@0.0.0 postbuild script 'npm run deploy'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the tasks package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     npm run deploy
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs tasks
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls tasks
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Michał\IdeaProjects\spring-angular2-tasks-master\Spring with Angular 4\src\main\frontend\npm-debug.log
```

My `package.json` file looks:

```
{
  "name": "tasks",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy-conf.json",
    "build": "ng build -prod",
    "postbuild": "npm run deploy",
    "predeploy": "rimraf ../resources/static/ && mkdirp ../resources/static",
    "deploy": "copyfiles -f dist/** ../resources/static",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^4.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.1.3",
    "@angular/core": "^4.1.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.1.3",
    "@angular/http": "^4.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.1.3",
    "@angular/router": "^4.1.3",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "copyfiles": "^1.2.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "mkdirp": "^0.5.1",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.1.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.47",
    "@types/node": "^7.0.22",
    "codelyzer": "~3.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.1.0",
    "karma": "1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.6.0",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "3.0.4",
    "tslint": "^5.3.2",
    "typescript": "~2.3.3"
  },
  "description": "This project was generated with [Angular CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) version 1.2.6.",
  "main": "karma.conf.js",
  "author": ""
}
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

UPDATE:
After running `npm run deploy` I have:

```
> tasks@0.0.0 predeploy C:\Users\Michał\IdeaProjects\spring-angular2-tasks-master\Spring with Angular 4\src\main\frontend
> rimraf ../resources/static/ && mkdirp ../resources/static


> tasks@0.0.0 deploy C:\Users\Michał\IdeaProjects\spring-angular2-tasks-master\Spring with Angular 4\src\main\frontend
> copyfiles -f dist/** ../resources/static

'copyfiles' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.15063
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "deploy"
npm ERR! node v6.9.4
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! tasks@0.0.0 deploy: `copyfiles -f dist/** ../resources/static`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the tasks@0.0.0 deploy script 'copyfiles -f dist/** ../resources/static'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the tasks package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     copyfiles -f dist/** ../resources/static
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs tasks
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls tasks
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Michał\IdeaProjects\spring-angular2-tasks-master\Spring with Angular 4\src\main\frontend\npm-debug.log
```

Comment: It's saying it's failing on the `npm run deploy` call. You should run that yourself and see what _that_ error looks like.

Comment: @Matt I have run it. Please see the update. There is a log.`

Comment: @bielas You should probably use Angular CLI for this. It is effective and gives more "readable" errors.

Comment: What do you mean by that. By Angular CLI I have created a components etc

Comment: Okay, now it says `copyfiles is not recognized as an internal or external command`. I'm not familiar with that npm package, let alone that package on Windows, but you should try playing around with that on the command line (by itself) and make sure it works as intended.

Comment: You mean to do it from cmd?

Comment: Tell the author that this fails on your system: npm ERR!     copyfiles -f dist/** ../resources/static

Comment: try `npm rebuild`

Comment: None of those solutions don't work

Answer (score 13):

Solve it by `npm install copyfiles -g`